# Upload file using ajax calls

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, webmethod

I looked through multiple tutorials, but none of it helps.
I have page with 4 controls and with tab-panel bootstrap theme. 
In code-behind of the page I want to save file that I uploaded:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["file"];
            var filName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var filePlace = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Uppladdat") + "\\" + filName;
            file.SaveAs(filePlace);
            return filePlace;

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

And for ajax request I use that code:

```
  function uploadFileAjax(file) {

            var formData = new FormData(file);
          //  formData.append("file", file);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Wizard.aspx/UploadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                processData: false, // Don't process the files
                contentType: false, // Set content type to false as jQuery will tell the server its a query string request
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function (errorThrown) {
                    // Handle errors here
                    console.log('ERRORS: ' + errorThrown);
                    // STOP LOADING SPINNER
                }
            });

        }
```

It returns to me successful result with page html except one string that I need so much.Also I tried to do some job with update panel, but it refreshes all the page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="uppladdadFil" type="file" name="uppladdadFil" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input id="Submit1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Bifoga" name="Submit1" runat="server" onserverclick="Submit1_ServerClick" />
                <input type="hidden" name="HiddenField1" id="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            </div>
            <div class="row top10">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblFilFelmeddelande" CssClass="label    label-danger" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Submit1" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Will be appreciated for any help to resolve that task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks that that link helps. At least I have access to the server side
http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/f2a2f1ee-e18a-416b-893e-883c800f83f4.aspx